# Digit Sum Property - Unique Numbers

Tags: number-theory

It says here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitSum.html
that the numbers $1, 81, 1458$ and $1729$ are each the product of their own digit sum and its reversal.

> These are the only four numbers with this property, as proved by Fujiwara (Fujiwara and Ogawa 2005).

I tried to find this source without success, only a few excerpts. It seems like it is not really a math paper or book but rather an interview between a professor and another person who back then was a Phd student or something. I could not find their proof.

> My question is if anyone knows of this proof or has an idea of how to show it.

To show that these numbers fulfill the condition is fairly simple. If anyone could provide a hint or an idea, it would be great and I could try to work it out by myself. I don't know how to start.

Comment: Well, it's a finite problem.  The digit sum  for $N$ is bounded by $9(\log_{10}N+1)$.  So, get a bound for the reverse and that will give you a bound on $N$.  After that, it's just a search.